# Is it safe to email SSL certificates?

Tags: linux, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, csr

When I purchase SSL certificates, I submit the CSR securely through the vendor's website. The vendor then emails me the certificate that I need to install on my server.

Is it safe to email the certificate like that? For example, if someone intercepted the email with my certificate, could they compromise/decrypt my SSL?

If so, what's the safest way to get the certificate from my vendor on to my server?

Comment: It is safe, because you still have the _private key_ kept safe.

Comment: [wpengine has a good article](http://wpengine.com/support/how-does-all-this-work-https-ssl-certificates-ca-public-and-private-keys-csrs/) explaining in plain language what the CA's role is.  Since the CA signs your certificate built around your _public key_, that component is public knowledge anyway. It is what your server sends to clients to decrypt traffic on the other end. As long as your _private key_ is protected, no other domain can impersonate yours.

Comment: Perhaps this question could be moved to https://serverfault.com/ ? I didn't find an equivalent question over there, but the question itself seems useful and well formulated, just on the wrong site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's safe, because this certificate is signed by a well-known certificate authority. You, and everyone who connects to your server, can validate the certificate to get assurance that the public key belongs to you alone.

In addition, you need to protect the *private* key that corresponds to the public key in the certificate. You must not disclose it to anyone: you don't need to send it to the certifying authority, and you shouldn't use a private key that was generated by anyone else.

The certificate is public; when you install it, it will be sent to everyone that connects as part of the process to authenticate your server.

If you use certificates that are not signed by a trusted certificate authority (self-signed, or signed by some private partner system), you'll need a way to make sure that everyone that wants to validate your certificate has a genuine root certificate, and not one that was tampered by an attacker.